# SAP commerce cloud migration from 1811 to 2211 - "getClass() cannot be found on type MediaModel" during Media indexing from backoffice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-expression-language, spring-expression

While doing **Media indexing** from backoffice for migration from 1811 to 2211. I am getting below error.

ERROR [solr indexer thread] [DefaultIndexerWorker] [Indexer worker 0 (FULL index operation on testMediaIndex/Media)] failed to process index items due to Failed to index item with PK 8817274191902: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8817274191902, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: externalURL, reason: EL1004E: Method call: Method getClass() cannot be found on type de.hybris.platform.core.model.media.MediaModel
de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Failed to index item with PK 8817274191902: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8817274191902, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: externalURL, reason: EL1004E: Method call: Method getClass() cannot be found on type de.hybris.platform.core.model.media.MediaModel
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.handleError(DefaultIndexer.java:304) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.indexItems(DefaultIndexer.java:207) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.executeIndexerOperation(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:245) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.execute(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:210) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.doRun(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:197) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.run(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:153) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.config.exceptions.FieldValueProviderException: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8817274191902, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: externalURL, reason: EL1004E: Method call: Method getClass() cannot be found on type de.hybris.platform.core.model.media.MediaModel
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.handleError(DefaultIndexer.java:662) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.addIndexedPropertyFieldsForOldApi(DefaultIndexer.java:473) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.addIndexedPropertyFields(DefaultIndexer.java:436) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.createInputDocument(DefaultIndexer.java:334) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.indexItems(DefaultIndexer.java:201) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]

I am using the below impex.
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; name[unique = true]; type(code); sortableType(code); currency[default = false]; localized[default = false]; multiValue[default = false]; useForSpellchecking[default = false]; useForAutocomplete[default = false]; fieldValueProvider; valueProviderParameter; facet[default = false];
; $solrIndexedMediaType ; externalURL ; string ; ; ; ; ; ; ; springELValueProvider ; **getClass().toString().contains("ExternalMedia")** ? externalURL : null ; ;

I think it's an issue with spring expression **getClass().toString().contains("ExternalMedia")**, same expression is working in 1811.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I am looking for SAP commerce cloud 2211 spring expression which is compatible with spring expression **getClass().toString().contains("ExternalMedia")**.

Comment: Your server might not init/start correctly. Double-check the java version, setantenv.bat, ant clean all, and start the server again. If you still face the issue. Please re-initialize.

Comment: @PinesTran Full indexing is working for Products, but failing on Media indexing as it cann't find getClass().toString().contains("ExternalMedia") on MediaModel. I checked in backoffice also this expression in available under indexed properties. I don't think it's an issue with initialization. Because same expression working with 1811.

Comment: This issue is fixed by "solrfacetsearch.fullSpELSupport=true" in local.properties file by default it's false.